# How to reload NetworkImageView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, reload, networkimageview

I have an app which is displaying fragment with one NetworkImageView widget from android Volley.

The image at URL which is loaded in NetworkImageView is changing every 5 secounds so I want to uptade this image by pressing reload button that I have created in action bar.

I have found 2 problems:

1. If I call this code for loading Image again(it was already called when the fragment was created at onActivityCreated() method):

   ```
   mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);
   mImageLoader = VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).getImageLoader();
   mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, mImageLoader);
   ```

so nothing will happens(it is not the actual IMG of that link), I think its because it is now loading IMG from cache and not from internet.

2. If I call fragment reload() method:

   ```
   public void reload(){

   MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
   IMAGE_URL = activity.getMyData();

   mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);

   mImageLoader = VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).getImageLoader();

   mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, mImageLoader);
   ```

from MainActivity:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {        
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_reload) {
        ViewFragment fragment = new ViewFragment();
        fragment.reload();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

app get NullPointerException error after clicking action bar reload button.

the reload(); method is the place where I would like to reload NetworkImageView.

Can someone explain me pls how to correct this issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the `cache` from `request queue`.

Then remove your `URL` from the `cache` by calling `remove` function from the cache ( the key is your url).

then use your first approach:

```
mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);
mImageLoader = VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).getImageLoader();
mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, mImageLoader);
```

Comment: Did you mean somthing like this? : AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(IMAGE_URL);

Comment: Can you help me also with calling my reload method from actionbar? because now I can only use this in fragment at onActivityCreated method like: when action bar reload is clicked I reload whole fragment and in onActivityCreated(of fragment) I load NetworkImageView then reset the cache and again load NetworkImageView but its still not downloading new IMG from internet.

Comment: No :-) because I can not understand what are you doing and what you are going to do? what are these lines ViewFragment fragment = new ViewFragment();fragment.Call();. you just instantiate a fragment and you  have not added it to your activity. you just create a fragment and call call.

Comment: fragment is added in to activity in another part of code. And the Call(); method is the place where I would like to have the code for reloading that NetworkImageView. And as I know the only way to call fragments method from activity is to do it like that.    ...I have writed it wrong in topic, its edited now.

Comment: If the fragment has already added to the mainactivity you must use get fragmentManager from your main activity and find the fragment you have added. that means you must add the fragment with a tag and find it by that tag. then you have access the one that has correct data. what have you done is just creating a fragment again without adding it to your activity .

Comment: Can you please link me some tutorial where is it explained? I would like to read it because that what you have writed its hard to understand for me. THX

Comment: I deliberately write it like that to make you feel you need to review the fragment concept again: First read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and then read whole lessens of [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html). those may have some extra information but it worth to spend some time to master the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

This question and answers look old but those answers doesn't work on my project.

For your help, I write my solution here.

The problem is Volley's `NetworkImageView` caching the image as a map  and there is no API for init the cache map.

Therefore my solution is make custom cache class which is includes removeCacheAll().

```
public class ImageCacheTrunk implements ImageLoader.ImageCache {

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        mCache.put(url, bitmap);

    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    return mCache.get(url);
    }

    public void removeCacheAll() {
        mCache.evictAll();
    }
}
```

and call removeCacheAll method before you need to reload.